# Somehow accidentally mixing TEdit.Text and TLabel.Caption works without exception?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, access-violation

I'm working with dynamically creating multiple different types of controls and storing them in a list in the background. Two of such controls are a TEdit and a TLabel. These controls are all sub-controls of a TPanel control.

Well I accidentally mixed up the TEdit with the TLabel when reading from TPanel.Controls (got them from the wrong indexes) when writing to the TEdit.Text and TLabel.Caption properties. Somehow, it didn't even raise any exception.

It does something like `TLabel(SomeEditControl).Caption:= 'This is a label control';` and `TEdit(SomeLabelControl).Text:= 'This is an edit control';` And it puts the TEdit.Text data in the TLabel.Caption property, and the TLabel.Caption data in the TEdit.Text property. I'm puzzled that this didn't raise an exception... The only thing I can guess is that the TEdit.Text and TLabel.Caption properties just so happen to use the same memory address between the control classes.

Why wouldn't this give an access violation?

Comment: They all descend from `TControl` which has a `WindowText` property. (
  Just guessing...)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That's a good possibility, TEdit.Text and TLabel.Caption I presume do translate to the WindowText

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TEdit.Text` comes from `TControl.Text`, and the `TLabel.Caption` comes from `TControl.Caption`. But look at the declaration of `TControl`:

```
...
property Caption: TCaption read GetText write SetText stored IsCaptionStored;
...
property Text: TCaption read GetText write SetText;
...
```

A control that has some text associated with it manages it via the `SetText` and `GetText` methods. Depending on the type of control, these are associated either with the `Caption` or the `Text` property. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TControl.Caption),

> **Note:** Controls that display text use either the Caption property or
>   the Text property to specify the text value. The property that is used
>   depends on the type of control. In general, Caption is used for text
>   that appears as a window title or label, while Text is used for text
>   that appears as the content of a control.

Comment: There's no `FText`, it's `WM_GETTEXT`, +1

Comment: Or `WM_SETTEXT` as a setter for those properties. +1ed, you were faster ;)

Comment: @David: Actually, there *is* an `FText`. Have a look at `SetText`. (But still, you are right. The main part seems to be based on these messages.)

Comment: That's probably why they removed Caption in FireMonkey. Every control now only has a Text property (except for forms, to keep it simple).

Comment: FText seemed to be only used for CLR when I read GetText, SetText etc.

Comment: @David: Yes, I revised my answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol in FireMonkey, nothing was 'removed' or 'added' based on VCL. Instead, FireMonkey is an entirely new raw system, not based on anything but OOP. But I understand your point. There are a lot of 'differences' in FM, not necessarily 'changes' from VCL.

Answer (score 1):

They're both derived from control class and both properties access value through same met